# Python will no longer run code within VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I had python working just fine in VSCode.

I started to go through the "Automate the boring stuff with python" course via Udemy. I followed the instructions and installed what the course had told me to do so via the terminal.

After that, VS Code would no longer execute or run my python code and I don't know enough to fix it. As you can see in the following [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSZLj.png) that a simple test results in an error.

It seems that the path is the issue but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Please help and walk me through the process if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: You've started a python process in the terminal and you're trying to run the shell command to run your script in that python process. Use the _shell_ (see the `zsh` thing just above `Python` on the right side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're inside the python console.
Try to run `quit()` first and then run your `.py` file again.